# Is it possible to execute a new application if the CPU Utilization of a computer is 100%?

Tags: cpu-usage

> The CPU Utilization of a computer is 100%.

Is it possible to execute a new application under the above condition?

Comment: It's impossible to say. If the operating system has some sort of scheduling, then yes, because sooner or later the process which controls the starting of new application will get its time share and be able to start it. If there's no OS or a real time OS, then the answer may be no.

Comment: If there is no OS, the "execute a new application" has no meaning.

Answer (score 5):

On operating systems with **preemptive multitasking** it is possible. The scheduler will interrupt the offending process so that other processes can get some time to run as well, but the offending process will still tend to hog the cpu and make the system feel very slow.

On OSes with **cooperative multitasking** it is only possible if the process which is using 100% of the CPU yields processor control.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking

Comment: A hardware interrupt will always, well, "interrupt" the CPU, no matter what else the CPU is doing. It would be possible for an operating system to be designed to respond to a hardware interrupt and launch an application even all CPU is being utilized.  The mechanism that most operating system schedulers use to "enforce" preemptive multitasking is hardware based.  Even under co-op multitasking systems an interrupt handler can change things, but this must part of the design beforehand.

Comment: Isn't that how preemption already does things? The CPU sends an interrupt at a regular interval which allows the scheduler to run and decide what gets to run next?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Assuming a "modern" operating system the available resources will be shared between processes, therefore if you have 1 application  (which is let's say 1 process) that received that 100%, by starting the 2nd application the OS will split that 100% into 50%-50%.